# ffmpeg include issue - some functions are missing

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, include

I try to follow and adapt this [example](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/0.6/output-example_8c-source.html) to convert a video thanks to FFMPEG but some function seems to be missing like :

```
int avcodec_open ( AVCodecContext * avctx, AVCodec * codec)
```

When I go in the doc to see where it come from, I find it in the file `libavcodec/avcodec.h` which is included in my program `#include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"` (in the top of my `.h` file).

Given this, I don't understand why Qt throw me this error :

```
../../Dev/Joker/libs/PhVideo/PhVideoEncoder.cpp:360:6: error: use of undeclared identifier 'avcodec_open'
    if (avcodec_open(c, codec) < 0) {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`avcodec_open` was deprecated and replaced with `avcodec_open2` in newer versions of FFMPEG.

Refer to latest [documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVCodec.html), [here](http://forum.openscenegraph.org/viewtopic.php?t=11961) and [here](http://patches.libav.org/patch/5819/)